# How to detect Tap event on Doughnut Shape created with CustomPainter

Tags: flutter, touch

I have created a custom Doughnut like shape using Flutter's CustomPainter class. Now I want to know which portion of the doughnut section user clicked. Based on that I need show some popup. I tried with DrawRect and DrawCircle and its working fine. But not able to do the same with DrawArc, can anyone please help me?

[image: Please have a look at this attached image]

Answer (score 0):

you can try GestureDetector and you can add your desired property like, onLongPress.

Comment: I am using GestureDetector and it works for drawCircle and drawRect but it won't work with circle made with multiple arcs.